# Enable to show session values in view - Laravel 5

Tags: php, session, laravel-5

am trying to show a simple value stored in session to a view, it is not working correctly

routes.php file

```
<?php
Route::get('/', 'Test@index');
Route::get('/nnn', 'Test@nnn');
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
});
```

controller file

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Session;

class Test extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        Session::put('name', 'abcdef');
         return view('welcome');

    }
    public function nnn(){

        return view('welcome');
    }
}
```

view file:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="title">Laravel 5</div>
            @if(Session::has('name'))
{{ Session::get('name') }}
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

when i go to localhost:8000   it is showing session value abcdef
but when i go to localhost:8000/nnn it is not showing any value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change your routes file to

```
<?php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
Route::get('/', 'Test@index');
Route::get('/nnn', 'Test@nnn');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in your controller method `nnn(){` echo `Session`, see what you get ? show me the results that you getting the value or not?

```
public function nnn(){
    echo Session::get('name') ;
    return view('welcome');
}
```

also try this in your view

```
{!! Session::get('name') !!}
```

instead

```
{{ Session::get('name') }}
```